# Django annotation on compoundish primary key with filter ignoring primary key resutling in too many annotated items

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

Please see EDIT1 below, as well.

Using Django 3.0.6 and python3.8, given following models

```
class Plants(models.Model):
    plantid = models.TextField(primary_key=True, unique=True)

class Pollutions(models.Model):
    pollutionsid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    plantid = models.ForeignKey(Plants, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='plantid')
    pollutant = models.TextField()
    releasesto = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(db_column="amount", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pollutions'
        unique_together = (('plantid', 'releasesto', 'pollutant', 'year'))

class Monthp(models.Model):
    monthpid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.IntegerField()
    plantid = models.ForeignKey(Plants, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='plantid')
    power = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'monthp'
        unique_together = ('plantid', 'year', 'month')
```

I'd like to annotate - based on a foreign key relationship and a fiter a value, particulary - to each plant the amount of co2 and the Sum of its power for a given year. For sake of debugging having replaced Sum by Count using the following query:

```
annotated = tmp.all().annotate(
energy=Count('monthp__power', filter=Q(monthp__year=YEAR)),
co2=Count('pollutions__amount', filter=Q(pollutions__year=YEAR, pollutions__pollutant="CO2", pollutions__releasesto="Air")))
```

However this returns too many items (a wrong number using Sum, respectively)

```
annotated.first().co2 # 60, but it should be 1
annotated.first().energy # 252, but it should be 1
```

although my database guarantees - as denoted, that (plantid, year, month) and (plantid, releasesto, pollutant, year) are unique together, which can easily be demonstrated:

```
pl = annotated.first().plantid
testplant = Plants.objects.get(pk=pl) # plant object
pco2 = Pollutions.objects.filter(plantid=testplant, year=YEAR, pollutant="CO2", releasesto="Air")
len(pco2) # 1, as expected
```

Why does django return to many results and how can I tell django to limit the elements to annotate to the 'current primary key' in other words to only annotate the elements where the foreign key matches the primary key?

I can achieve what I intend to do by using distinct and Max:

```
energy=Sum('yearly__power', distinct=True, filter=Q(yearly__year=YEAR)),
co2=Max('pollutions__amount', ...
```

However the performance is inacceptable.

I have tested to use model_to_dict and appending the wanted values "by hand" to the dict, which works for the values itself, but not for sorting the resulted dict (e.g. by energy) and it is acutally faster than the workaround directly above.

It conceptually strikes to me that the manual approach is faster than letting the database do, what it is intended to do.

Is this a feature limitation of django's orm or am I missing something?

EDIT1:
[The behaviour is known as bug since 11 years.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060)
Even others "spent a whole day on this".

I am now trying it with subqueries. However the forein key I am using is not a primary key of its table. So the kind of "usual" approach to use "pk=''" does not work. More clearly, trying:

```
tmp = Plants.objects.filter(somefilter)

subq1 = Subquery(Yearly.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('plantid'), year=YEAR))  tmp1 = tmp.all().annotate(
        energy=Count(Subquery(subq1))
    )
```

returns

```
OperationalError at /xyz
no such column: U0.yid
```

Which definitely makes sense because Plants has no clue what a yid is, it only knows plantids. How do I adjust the subquery to that?

Comment: Because of the double `JOIN`ing, the two items are a "multiplier" for each other.

Comment: Thanks to your hint I found the bug I mentioned in my edited post. However I am still stuck.